# Html.DisplayFor Compile Error - MVC 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, view

I'm getting the following error:

```
The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor<TModel,TValue>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TValue>>, string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

Here is my partial View:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyApp.Data.Person>" %>
```

> ```
> <fieldset>
>
>     <legend>Information</legend>
>
>     <div class="display-label">ID</div>
>     <div class="display-field"><%: Model.ID %></div><br />
>
>     <div class="display-label">Name</div>
>     <div class="display-field"><%: Model.Name %></div><br />
>
>     <div class="display-label">DOB</div>
>     <div class="display-field"><%: String.Format("{0:g}", Model.DOB) %></div><br />
>
>
>     <div class="display-label">On Alert</div>
>     <div class="display-field"><%: Html.DisplayFor(Model.OnAlert, "FormBoolean") %></div><br />
>
>     <div class="display-label">Deactivated</div>
>     <div class="display-field"><%: Model.Deactivated %></div><br />
>
> </fieldset>
> ```

Here is my FormBoolean display template:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Boolean>" %>
<div class="formValueShort"><%= Html.Encode(Model ? "Yes" : "No") %></div>
```

Can anyone shed any light on this? I've also tried 'LabelFor' (without including 'FormBoolean'), HiddenFor, EditorFor - all give the same message. It's strange because I have used these through my project so I'm not sure why it's stuck on this particular one.

Let me know if I need to provide any more information!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first parameter of `DisplayFor` is a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). You need to call like this:

```
<%: Html.DisplayFor(m => m.OnAlert, "FormBoolean") %>
```

Comment: Ah! So simple! It's been a long day! Thanks a lot. I'll mark your answer as correct when the time limit is up :)